# SSRS 2008 Toggle visibility of rows based on data contained in row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am developing a report in SSRS 2008 R2 that is based on a dataset that has a column "row type" and I need to hide the initial visibility based on the valu contained in that column (only two values are returned) and then be able to toggle the visibility of the rows. The dataset is returning both the detail and summary rows - detail first then summary for each group - grouping and sorting being done in the stored procedure (no grouping in the report). This is a requirement that is out of my hands. What I would like to accomplish is having the detail rows hidden when the report is run with a toggle indicator on each summary row that when clicked will display the detail rows for that summary. Is this possible?

Comment: Forgot to add - I have the initial visibility working that hides the detail row - just need to figure out the toggling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create groups. If you have some way that your summary rows from the dataset are linked to specific data rows, then you should group on that.

Or you could group on the "Row Type" column. Keep the formula you are currently using for detail row visibility, and use the group header to toggle visibility. You can hide the group header for your summary rows using a visibility formula with the logical inverse of your current formula. This will it visible for the detail rows.

[image: Row Visibility dialog from SSRS BIDS]

Comment: Thanks James - good thought but did not work - Error: "Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item, cannot be contained within the current report item unless current group scope has a Parent" This report has no grouping.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by summary rows if you don't have groupings. Could you clarify what a summary row is?

Comment: All rows are detail rows to the report - as stated in the original queation - grouping and sorting is done in the stored procedure that provides data to the report. There is no grouping on the report - there is a column called rowtype that contains either a "S" or a "D" and my code for the initial visibility is =iif(Fields!rowtype.Value="D",false,true) - this hides the "Detail" rows when the report is run.

Comment: Ahh. The details of your question just clicked for me. I'll fill in more details in my answer later today, but you should create a grouping. You can display data from the "summary" rows in the SSRS group summary row and hide and display the detail row from there.